# Add New status for magento reviews

Tags: magento-1.9, review, product-review

How can I add new status for reviews?

I want to do that from installer.

My code is kinda like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `review_status` (`status_code`) VALUES ('Approved And Verified');
";

try {
    $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $conn->query($sql);
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The status is added in database but not usable/seen in admin in order to change a review status.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part from installer was good but also i needed to rewrite Helper and Model for Mage_Review:

```
class Custom_Review_Helper_Data extends Mage_Review_Helper_Data
{
    public function getReviewStatuses()
    {
        return array(
            Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED                       => $this->__('Approved'),
            Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING                        => $this->__('Pending'),
            Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_NOT_APPROVED                   => $this->__('Not Approved'),
            Custom_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED_AND_VERIFIED        => $this->__('Approved And Verified')
        );
    }
}



class Custom_Review_Model_Review  extends Mage_Review_Model_Review {

    const STATUS_APPROVED_AND_VERIFIED  = 4;

}
```